# Set tab width in GUI terminal

Tags: terminal, xterm, rxvt

I found that

```
setterm -regtabs 4
```

doesn't work in xterm or urxvt.

But, this

```
xterm_set_tabs () { 
  TERM=linux;
  export $TERM;
  setterm -regtabs 4
}
```

will circumvent the problem.

But, I suspect it is suboptimal as (1) I get a gfx bug I can't otherwise explain (at least, if I get the tab stuff right that possibility is ruled out), and (2) when I ssh to my school's Solaris, and run `emacs -nw`, it says the terminal "linux" is unknown! So then I have to change it back to "xterm". Of course, this is silly as all the while I'm using the same terminal.

Also, perhaps not relying on tabs at all is a good rule of thumb!

Answer (score 8):

The `setterm` utility is intended for use with the Linux console.  According to the [console_codes manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html):

> The Linux console implements a large subset of the VT102 and
>   ECMA-48/ISO 6429/ANSI X3.64 terminal controls, plus certain private-
>   mode sequences for changing the color palette, character-set mapping,
>   and so on.

Since the [program is hard-coded](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/term-utils/setterm.c#n968),

```
/* -regtabs. */
if (ctl->opt_regtabs && vc_only(ctl, "--regtabs")) {
    int i;

    fputs("\033[3g\r", stdout);
    for (i = ctl->opt_rt_len + 1; i <= TABS_MAX; i += ctl->opt_rt_len)
        printf("\033[%dC\033H", ctl->opt_rt_len);
    putchar('\r');
}
```

it just happens to work with xterm since xterm implements [VT100 controls (plus more)](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html).

As for **large subset**, that is debatable.  In a quick count of the items in `console_codes`, I see 79 control sequences.  That is far less than any of the xterm look-alikes documented in the xterm FAQ [Comparing versions, by counting controls](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#compare_versions).  By itself, 79 is not large. The VT102 itself (not an xterm look-alike) had 104.  ISO-6429 (aka [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)) documents 20 modes and 162 sequences.  Whether you count the total as 182 or 162, 50% is not a *large subset*.

Rather than using a Linux console utility, there is a more portable choice: the `tabs` utility (in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tabs.html) as well as Solaris).  It is part of the [ncurses utilities](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tabs.1.html) (and probably installed on your Linux system).

For the example given in the question, you could do this:

```
tabs -4
```

That uses the terminal database, rather than being hard-coded.  Tabs and the control sequences to set them are documented in ECMA-48 and other places such as the [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual page.

And **`tabs`** works with xterm.

Comment: Where has *that* been all my life?!  Some program I use is forever cocking up my tab stops, and I don't know (or care) which one it is.  I just wanted my tab stops back.  What's the procedure for hijacking a question so I can mark it answered?  The embarrassing part is that a simple `man -k tab|grep -i -v table |grep -i -v database` would have uncovered it *decades* ago.

Answer (score 4):

Many terminals support escape sequences that set tab stops. The capability has even an entry in terminfo(5): tbc (clear all tabs) and hts (horizontal tab set).

```
$ tput tbc; echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa$(tput hts); echo 'a\tb'
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
a                    b
```

Above we set a tab stop at the end of those aaaaaaaa, and we see the result on next line.

So, to set the tab stops, every 4 colums, we need:

```
tbc=$(tput tbc) hts=$(tput hts) cuf4=$(tput cuf 4)
printf '%s\r' "$tbc"
i=4
while [ "$i" -lt "$COLUMNS" ]; do
  printf %s "$cuf4$hts"
  i=$(($i + 4))
done
printf '\r'
```

Or you can also set tab stops at irregular intervals. Above we used "tput cuf"
to move the cursor forward, while in the first example we used "aaaa". You can do:

```
printf '\r%s' "${tbc}aaaa${hts}aaaaa${hts}aaaaaaaa${hts}"
```

to set one tab stop at the 4th column, then the next one, 5 columns further...

Comment: Will this set the general tab width so that `\t = "    "` if the tab width is 4? (Imagine four spaces, seems I can't write that.)

Comment: OK, I see you've made an edit, answering my comment above. You seem to know a lot about this... Check out my answer below, is there a practical difference or are your solution simply much cooler?

Comment: Hello again, just tried this and it breaks the cursor movement in `emacs -nw` just like my solution below.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the environment variable temporarily without needing to export it to your whole session using `env`:

```
env TERM=linux setterm -regtabs 4
```

Comment: That is better.

Comment: Tried this, same problem as described in my post, and in the comment to sch's post.

Answer (score 2):

In response to @Jim Paris:

Note that that only works for terminals that support the same escape sequences as linux virtual terminals to set tabs (and move the cursor forward).For instance, using "cat -v", we can see what sequence setterm is sending:

```
$ TERM=linux setterm -regtabs 4 | cat -vte
^[[3g^M^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^[[4C^[H^M
```

Luckily, it's the same sequences as supported by xterm:

```
~$ TERM=xterm tput tbc | cat -vte
^[[3g
~$ TERM=xterm tput hts | cat -vte
^[H
~$ TERM=xterm tput cuf 4 | cat -vte
^[[4C
```

And as it's the case of vt100, it's likely to be the case of most termnial emulators.

Comment: Better yet would probably be to set it native in xterm, urxvt, etc., not going sideways to the Linux virtual terminal. I suspect there is an `.Xresources` option for this; I'll keep looking. (Above, isn't it enough with `cat -t`?)

Answer (score -2):

OK, I've read `man xterm` and there is no mention of tab width. I'm starting to think it is easiest just to reset `TERM`. In `.bashrc`:

```
function xterm_set_tabs () {
  TERM=linux
  export $TERM
  setterm -regtabs 4
  TERM=xterm
  export $TERM
}

if [ `echo $TERM` == "xterm" ]; then
  xterm_set_tabs
fi
```

**Edit**: This works for the problem described, but it has the side effect that when I run `emacs -nw` the cursor movement is messed up. As that is very serious, this is not an acceptable solution to the problem. (I'm unsure about site policy - should I remove my answer, or should I leave it so others will learn from the mistake as well? Obviously, I think it should remain. Anyhow, back to the drawing board.)

Comment: TERM=linux setterm -regtabs 4

is how you set the TERM variable to linux **only** for the setterm command. Are you sure you'll run that only in xterm terminals?

Comment: So far the above has worked, the display in xterm is correct and I can ssh and then `emacs -nw`, but I'm absolutely not sure of any under the hood workings in this case. There are a lot of suggestions already, if you know their pros and cons, do tell, that's why we are here :)