# Setting tab width in C++ output in bash

Tags: terminal, columns, text-formatting

I have a `c++` program and I use the tab character `"\t"` to organize my output to a human-readable columns. However, 8-spaces-wide column in bash is too narrow for me. How can I increase it?

**Note:** In C++ forums people say: *"C++ just outputs the character and is not responsible for the visible output"*. In linux forums people say: *"It is the program you use to output to terminal that is responsible for this, probably `less` or so."*

Comment: how are you viewing your program on the terminal, is it using a pager such as less or and editor like vi?

Comment: No, no "viewer". I open the terminal and type `./a.out` or whatever is the name of the binary.

Comment: If you don't use any viewer, it's the programs role to format the output accordingly. If you were to use a pager or a text editor or processor, maybe, but just MAYBE, this intermediary software could represent tabs as N (N being customizable) spaces.

Comment: If I redirect the ouput to a file like `./a.out > file.txt`, then the file contains the tab character. So obviously, the program sends the tab character to the terminal and it's a role of the terminal to typeout it correctly.

Comment: Also, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46368/set-tab-width-in-gui-terminal?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the tab stops in your terminal using the terminal database, which you can access several ways from C++ (for example, ncurses). You can also access it from shell using `tput`.

You'd want to start by clearing the tabs (`tput tbc`). Then move the cursor to each column you want a tab stop in (`tput hpa 10` for column 10, for example). Then finally set the tab stop (`tput hts`). Repeat the positioning and tab setting for each tab stop you want. Example:

```shell
echo -e '0\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8'
tput tbc
for ((i=0; i<`tput cols`; i+=10)); do
    tput hpa $i
    tput hts
done
tput hpa 0
echo -e '0\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8'
```

Comment: So I can put something like `tput tbc` `tput hpa 10` `tput hts` `tput hpa 20` `tput hts` ... into my `.bashrc` and just be happy?

Comment: @tohecz yes, you can put that in your bashrc, but that'll change tabstops every bash shell you have. You may not want it for all your shells. You can also use ncurses, etc. in your program, and then just have it take effect when you run your program.

Answer (score 4):

So, the printed tab character is fixed within the source code of the program. I don't think that the display of the tab character in bash can be edited in a shell setting.

I'm just guessing here, but I think the representation of the tab character is embedded within the character encoding set that your terminal program is using. The ASCII character set defines the tab character, but the UTF-8 character set [doesn't seem to](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/). I don't think any character encoding set uses a different width for the tab character, so I think you're out of luck unless you want to write your own character set and use it, but that sounds like a headache waiting to happen.

Instead, have you tried the `pr` command?

> PR(1)          User Commands         PR(1)
>
> NAME
>          pr - convert text files for printing

To swap tab characters for 10 spaces, you could do this:-

```
./a.out | pr --expand-tabs=10 -t
```

Comment: `pr` paginates the output, which is frowned upon. Can this be disabled?

Comment: @tohecz the `-T` option disable pagination

Comment: `-t` option. Will update answer...

Comment: Ok, so it seems to help, thanks. However, having to pipe it seems a bit strange to me and means you have to call it another way to output it tab-seperated to a file etc.

Comment: Well, you could output it to file once, complete with tabs, and then run `pr .. ` directly on the tab-delimited file. e.g. `./a.out > output.txt ; pr --expand-tabs=10 -t output.txt`

Answer (score 3):

C++ isn't responsible for the width. I had a longer response typed up but it really became unnecessary when I did a test...

Basically, use `tabs` (part of the ncurses5 package)... e.g.

```
zsh> tabs 4 # 4 space width tabs
zsh> ./a.out
```

This will format to your width you want automatically. No need to pipe (which doesn't help if you have interactive work).

Comment: I've edited in which package the `tabs` command comes from in case someone doesn't have it installed. Feel free to revert my edit if you do not approve.

Comment: Thanks @derobert I wasn't sure as it came preinstall on my CentOS 6 box and I didn't check to see what provided it.

Answer (score 2):

As illustrated in the other answers, the [`tabs`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tabs.1.html) utility is the simpler way to *specify* tab stops for applications (such as your shell) which do not set their own tab stops. POSIX specifies a [`tabs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tabs.html) utility, (as well as [`tput`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tput.html)), but has nothing to say about terminfo or the behavior of `tput` for this purpose. (X/Open Curses, which is a separate standard, does have something to say).

But to use those tab stops, you should also ensure that your terminal is setup to use hardware tabs.  If you do [`stty -a`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html), look for `tab0` in the output:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

According to the `stty` manual, you should be able to set `tab0` or `tab3`.  POSIX defines `tab1` and `tab2`, but only `tab0` (hardware tabs) and `tab3` (software tabs) are useful to you.

> **`tab0 tab3`**
>   Select tab expansion policy.  **`tab0`** disables tab expansion, while **`tab3`** enables it.

Further reading:

- [*Portability*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tabs.1.html#h2-PORTABILITY), in ncurses [tabs](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tabs.1.html) manual page
- [*Portability*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-PORTABILITY), in ncurses [tput](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) manual page